# Cannot route local traffic through local gateway

Tags: networking, routing

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6002]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 25 ...00 03 0d 11 0b 30 ...... QF9700 USB2.0 To Fast Ethernet Adapter #2
 10 ...00 00 00 00 00 00 ...... Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Family PCI Gigabit Ethern
et NIC (NDIS 6.0)
  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1
 11 ...02 00 54 55 4e 01 ...... Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.10    257
         10.0.0.0  255.255.255.192    10.35.133.193    10.35.133.230     21
    10.35.133.192  255.255.255.192         On-link     10.35.133.230    276
    10.35.133.230  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.35.133.230    276
    10.35.133.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.35.133.230    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.10    257
     192.168.1.10  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.10    257
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.10    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.35.133.230    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.10    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.35.133.230    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.10    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
         10.0.0.0  255.255.255.192    10.35.133.193       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 10    276 ::/0                     fe80::21a:a9ff:fe6d:4749
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 10    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 25    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    276 fe80::309b:6e26:2534:bbbf/128
                                    On-link
 25    276 fe80::b00d:9184:d5e8:754/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 25    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Windows\System32>tracert 10.35.130.10

Tracing route to 10.35.130.10 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    33 ms    33 ms    33 ms  117.216.248.1
  3    34 ms    34 ms    34 ms
```

Here is the problem:

As it can be seen, though the persistent route tells to route the local traffic through 10.35.133.193, it is getting routed to 192.168.1.1. Please help.

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "local traffic"? Do you mean traffic to 10.35.130.10? What makes that "local"?

Answer (score 1):

According to your tracert result, it's absolutely normal that 10.35.130.10 routed to 192.168.1.1(default GW). As you can see, only 10.0.0.0/26(10.0.0.0 ~ 10.0.0.64) will be routed to 10.35.133.193. There are no route for 10.35.130.10, therefore it's routed to default GW. Just add 10.35.130.10's network entry routed to 10.35.133.193.

Comment: or you can just change 10.0.0.0/26 to 10.0.0.0/8(255.0.0.0) if local traffic uses all of 10.0.0.0/8.